# pip fails to upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

While running the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I receive the following output:
[image]

Which includes two errors:

```
1: AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

2: KeyError: 'No metadata except PKG-INFO is available'
```

I'm using python3.7.1 with fresh install.

I couldn't find any solutions to the issue. Anyone knows how to handle that?

Comment: Please see if this helps
https://github.com/cloudpractise/PKG-INFO-Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my `pip fails to upgrade problem` on Windows 10:

1) I had two versions of python installed and my previous version was added to the `PATH` variable, so I removed the previous `PATH` and added there my new Python version which was 3.7.1

2) Next I removed the previous version of Python and restarted my system.

I don't whether this will work or not but it worked for me.

Hope it helps :)